# ASP.NET Timeout Setting (IE and Chrome)

Tags: c#, java, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have an asp.net web application. It communicates to business layer through WCF. There is a function that takes more than one hour to complete. It is a usual synchronous call.
For testing purpose, Thread.Sleep is is used in business layer (service) to reproduce this function.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4200000);
```

I am testing it with Visual Studio 2005 dev env (not IIS). When I tested with chrome as web browser, it can wait even after one hour. But when I tested with IE6, it is logging out the application exactly after one hour and it navigates to our login page.

**Any thoughts about what settings I should make to not log out in IE even after 1 hour?**

Note: This functionality is used once in a month only by administrator. So taking two hours is okay for us. [Creating something like a windows app for the admin may be ideal. But we cannot think of that at this point of time.]. Also we cannot create any other Ajax call or duplex service –those things are not permitted by client. So the only solution is changing setting for IE (either in IE or in ASP.NET)

Note: The WCF is self hosted for testing. It is NetTCPBinding in WCF.

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: I recommend to avoid designs like this. It is more robust to run asynchronous execution, save results to database and then show the result on demand.

Comment: Assuming it's not a function that has to be called very often (or at least I hope so) just using a browser other than IE6 is not an option for this specific function?

Comment: I agree with Alex.There is no point in having such long running HTTP request. In most environments, if not browser then router/switch over the network is likely to timeout the HTTP connection.

Comment: @thekip: There is a third party control which is not compatible with other browsers. Hence we need to make it working with IE. @VinayC How can I determine which one caused the HTTP Connection timeout? Any tool/method to figure out that? Can tcpdump help?  Also why this did not happen for chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Web.config to increase the amount of time a Session stays active for:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=vls.dev.videolibraryserver.com;User Id=sa;Password=test;" timeout="300" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: change the timeout value

Then write an ajax control that polls the WCF service, when it is complete then reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the WCF service then I recommend that you refactor your code.

It really is not good practise to have such a long running process happening synchronously.

If you know that it's going to take that long and are not worried about the result you could use a OneWay service, then your client wouldn't have to wait for a reply.

If you wrote a duplex service then your client may time still as it wouldn't get a callback for such a long time.

Another solution is to use the OneWay service and then create another service that polls to see if the operation is complete, as suggested by Pete2k